# When comparing text files with diff, it marks two identical files as different, why?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to compare two text files in bash using `diff`. I have two identical (to the eye) files and as I understand it, diff returns, that every single line is different?

```
diff "file1" "file2"

1,11c1,11
< 2
< 1
< 2
< 1
< 2
< 1
< 2
< 1
< 2
< 1
< 2
---
> 2
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 2
```

Comment: Did you save one in Windows notepad and the other not?  Your line endings might be jacked up.

Comment: One file is generated in C on my Mac, the other I got and not sure about the machine it was made on. How do I check for line endings?

Comment: Some Editors have the ability to show them. On Windows I would recommend Notepad++.

Comment: I would love to hear the reason for a downvote of my bash scripting question?

Comment: cat -v file1 > file3;cat -v file2 > file4 ; diff file3 file4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what GUI editors are in Mac but assuming you're in OS X you can use the terminal and open each file with `vi`.  When you have a file opened, type `:set list` to show line endings and `:set nolist` to revert back.  `:set ff` will give you whether it's a Unix or DOS type file.

From there just delete each one or you can use a `unix2dos` or `dos2unix` utility to convert between the two formats.

Comment: I use vim, and your suggestions will be useful way into the future :) So thanks!